# guardar una lista de tuplas en un fichero y leerla con Python

Tags: python

tengo una lista de tuplas con esta forma:

```
[('lo que sea','dfasdf','3'),
('lo quefgfdg sea','dfadsfgf','4'),....]
```

Necesito guardarla en un fichero para leerla más tarde en otros módulos, el problema es que con un fichero normal de texto no me vale, ya que no veo la forma de leerla luego con el mismo formato de lista de tuplas.

¿Como podría hacerlo?

Comment: ¿Quieres extraer los datos en modo tupla o quieres guardarlos como tuplas sin que te devuelva lo de `<class 'tuple'>`? Que yo sepa, al guardar algo en un fichero desde python, lo guarda en formato de strings y recuperas la string tal cual la guardas.

Comment: En caso de que quieras guardar **el contenido** de las tuplas,  tendras que pasar por todos los valores e ir añadiéndolos uno por uno a tu archivo (en el formato que quieras. Por ejemplo: separado por comas, por espacios, etc.). Después, para leer el contenido del archivo, tendrías que hacerlo transformando lo que leas del archivo (siguiendo el patrón tal cual lo guardaste) de `str` al formato que quieras (En caso de querer guardarlo en una tupla, tendrás que crear una nueva tupla y añadirlo ahí). Te recomiendo que visites docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#bltin-file-objects.

Comment: Si quieres una explicación más extensa, dimelo por comentario y me pondré con ello. Espero que sirva, ¡un saludo!

Comment: Si todas las tuplas tienen los mismos campos ¿por qué no usas un csv sin más, cada tupla una fila?. Puedes usar pickcle o guardar la representación de la misma como tal y usar std.literal_eval pero un csv es muy simple y portable.

Comment: Como se usaria pickle? no conozco ese método.

Comment: Lo que quiero es leer esta lista de tuplas del fichero para ahorrar tiempo de cómputo que sin hacer esto me tardaria el programa la vida. Con lo cual me gustaria saber la opción más rapida para leer del fichero.

Comment: Es un sistema propio de Python que permite serializar objetos arbitrarios: https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html

Comment: ¿Todas las tuplas tienen el mismo número  de items (tres en el ejemplo)?

Comment: Si, todas son como en el ejemplo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes varias formas de serializar una lista de tuplas con el mismo número de items, teniendo en cuenta solo opciones incluidas en Python estándar, por ejemplo:

### Usar un csv:

**`ESCRITURA`**

```
import csv

lista = [('lo que sea','dfasdf','3'),
         ('lo quefgfdg sea','dfadsfgf','4')]

# Escritura
with open("lista.csv", "w", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter=",")
    writer.writerows(lista)
```

**`LECTURA`**

```
with open("lista.csv", "r", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter=",")
    lista = [tuple(row) for row in reader]
```

### Usar pickle

**`ESCRITURA`**

```
import pickle

with open('lista.pickle', 'wb') as file:
    pickle.dump(lista, file, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
```

**`LECTURA`**

```
import pickle

# Lectura
with open('lista.pickle', 'rb') as file:
    lista = pickle.load(file)
```

### Usar una base de datos SQLite3

**`ESCRITURA`**

```
import sqlite3

lista = [('lo que sea','dfasdf','3'),
         ('lo quefgfdg sea','dfadsfgf','4')]

con = sqlite3.connect("data.db")
con.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS lista")
con.execute("create table lista (col1 varchar, col2 varchar, col3 varchar)")
with con:
    con.executemany("insert into lista values (?, ?, ?)", lista)
con.close()
```

**`LECTURA`**

```
import sqlite3

con = sqlite3.connect("data.db")

with con:
    lista = list(con.execute("SELECT * FROM lista"))
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu comentario, parece que en principio me esta funcionando, pero tengo un fallo. Al guardar en el CSV, se me queda una linea vacia entre medias de cada registro, esto hace que al final en la lista se culen () vacios. Como podria solucionarlo?

Comment: Definitivamente la opción de pickle me ha servido. Como ultima pregutna, esto serviria para cualquier tipo de estructura de datos, si por ejemplo tengo [[[ 65.59129272  93.54390924 138.22917845]]] podria utilizar el dump de pickle igualmente?